# IIS / PHP7.2 $_SERVER['Path'] not matching

Tags: php, iis-7

To preface, I'm used to working with Linux/Nginx, but have to use IIS for this project.

I've set up php7.2, using fcgi on IIS, and I'm having issues where the Path over CLI isn't matching the Path over FCGI.

**CLI**

```
$_SERVER['Path'] => E:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\BIN;E:\PHP7.2;E:\PHP7.2\ext;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Users\kkeiper1103\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\kkeiper1103\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

**FCGI**

```
$_SERVER['Path'] => C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.2;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Users\kkeiper1103\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

Where do I set my Path in IIS so that it has the correct values?

Comment: Because the FastCGI process is launched by a Windows service in session 0 as the application pool identity, so its environment variables are completely different from what you get at CLI (your own account) in a user session. To configure environment variables for different scenarios, learn commands like `setx`.

Answer (score 0):

FastCGI is correct?

Configuration:

[image: Configuration]

Comment: IMO this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)